# how to setup bashrc bash_profile

Tags: linux, macos, path, path-variables

Hi I am newbie to pathvariables. I get the `rvm` path as `/local/rvm/` when I do `locate rvm` . So I assume that its in the /local folder.

But when I do the `$ rvm` It complaints about the command not found. Can you please tell me what the path variable should be if my rvm is installed in /local/ location.

my .bash_profile looks something like this:

`[[ -s "$HOME/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

Thanks

Comment: `$HOME/local` is quite distinct from `/local`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

It doesn't look like this is a path issue. `rvm` is a script that loads a function, and so it does not need to be in your path.

You need to find where the actual `rvm/scripts` folder resides. If it really has ended up in a root-level `/local` folder, then you need to edit that .bash_profile line to remove the `$HOME` part of both lines...

So I would suggest figuring out where that file actually exists. I think the `locate` command is finding the `rvm` directory and not the command itself...

Does `ls /local/rvm/scripts/` show you the contents of a folder?

On the [`rvm` page](https://rvm.io/rvm/install), it shows it as being installed in a `.rvm` directory of your home directory...

Comment: Yes, it does show the contents if I do ls for the /local/rvm/scripts so now my the the line should look like this? `[[ -s "$/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`?

Comment: Like that but without either `$`

Comment: Thanks for the help! It didnt solve the issue but appreciate the effort! The thing was my vm was using tcsh as default bash so I had to convert that to bash. :) +1